# Using scrapy extract the url of image

Tags: image, url, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape images. I notice that some image url is specified by @src,like the following:

```
<a href="http://www.wandoujia.com/apps/com.uu">
            <img src="http://img.wdjimg.com/mms/icon/v1/5/09/14687d011083dc84036fc68dc3c80095_68_68.png" width="68" height="68" alt="UU电话" class="icon">
</a>
```

Some are different:

```
<a href="http://www.wandoujia.com/apps/com.hcsql.shengqiandianhua">
            <img data-original="http://img.wdjimg.com/mms/icon/v1/6/44/a27006acfbe8b6aa39bee49c6f004446_68_68.png" alt="省钱电话" class="icon lazy" width="68" height="68" src="http://img.wdjimg.com/mms/icon/v1/6/44/a27006acfbe8b6aa39bee49c6f004446_68_68.png" style="display: block;">
</a>
```

I use the following code to extract. The result is : 1)if only the src occur, the @src is the real link of image; 2) if the data-original occurs, the @data-original is the real link,@src is not. So my question is what should i do if I want to extract the url  of the image under the both two cases.

```
sel.xpath('/a/img/@src').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sel.xpath('//a/img[not(@data-original)]/@src | //a/img/@data-original').extract()
```